# Remote ejb call failed after successful calls

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I've a strange problem. 
I've install JbossAS 7.1.1 and deployed my ear file successfully.

My client is running to tomcat 6.035.

I can make successful EJB calls to my jboss deployment - but one specific EJB calls fails.

my client environment setup is as below :-

```java
  Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

  env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
  env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
  env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "abc");
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "123");
  env.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
  env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");

  env.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
  env.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");
  //env.put("remote.connection.x1.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");

  logger.debug("Added security ");

  try {
    ctx = new InitialContext(env);
  } catch (NamingException e) {
    logger.error("Can't get initial context.");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

The  stracktrace is very strange. Its looking for  RemoteNamingEJBClient 
Please help - I'm out of idea.

```
  18:03:25,541 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (EJB default - 8) Failed to define class org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ejb.RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector in Module "org.jboss.remote-naming:main" from local module loader @50988 (roots:  jbossAS7/modules): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/naming/remote/client/ejb/RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector (Module "org.jboss.remote-naming:main" from local module loader @50988 (roots: jbossAS7/modules))


  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/ejb/client/ContextSelector


  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.ejb.client.ContextSelector from [Module "org.jboss.remote-naming:main" from local module loader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem by adding

ejb-client module in remote-naming module

this issue is tracked here-

## https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4872

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="jboss-remote-naming-1.0.2.Final.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.ejb-client" />
    <module name="org.jboss.remoting3"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.marshalling"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.marshalling.river"/>
</dependencies>
```