# How to get a DataSource hosted on a server in a java se application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, datasource

I need to get a DataSource object in my java se application without setting the username and password.

```
dataSource=(DataSource)ic.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
```

Something similar to this.

Im using JBOSS EAP 6.4 and Oracle database.

Is it possible to get the datasource hosted on the local server from within a java se application? If so can you give me some concrete example? I tried https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Separate JVM’s?

Comment: the app will run on the same machine as the server

Comment: As per details provided in link, you are using JNDI without application server. Can you please share how you registered your object to JNDI on local JVM ? But as per your question it seems that you want to lookup object on JBOSS appplication server. Can you clarify what you want to achieve [both things are possible but need more details] ?

Comment: The datasource is registered to JNDI using the standalone.xml configuration file in the jboss install directory. The jboss server is hosting a web app that uses the datasource and it works. I want to get the datasource from another separate java application that will run outside the web container but on the same machine as the server.

Comment: I need this because i am not allowed to use the DriverManager class and also not allowed to set the username and password of the database in code.

Comment: Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://<hostname>:port");
context = new InitialContext(properties);
DataSource myDataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup(" Remote JNDI Name"); Also ensure that remote JNDI lookup is not disable on server.

Comment: any idea where is the "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory" class located? im getting a class not found exception. And also in properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://<hostname>:port");. what do i set? If the server is running on localhost do i put localhost:8080 or what.

Comment: i tried using System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces"); before

Comment: hostname : localhost and port where admin server is running. Most of the application server provides JEE jar please find JEE jar and put in your calsspath. <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-7.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: imported the jar containing that class(jboss-remote-naming-1.0.10.Final-redhat-1) but now i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xnio/Options Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xnio.Options

Comment: `        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:9990");
        Context context = null;
        try {
            context = new InitialContext(properties);
            DataSource myDataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/HexaSecurity");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }'

Comment: it is jboss class i think it is used for connecting to remote server, kindly refer to thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005838/remote-ejb-call-failed-after-successful-calls, person has simillar problem while conneting to remote JNDI object on Jboss, you need to import more jar

Comment: JNDI is only useful for sharing objects in the _same_ JVM.  If you are "outside" the application server, you need to communicate with code in the server to have it do what you need.   Note that Java EE clients are capable of exactly this!  JBoss should support it.

Comment: i think i added all the jars i need, but now im getting this expection any idea why?  javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://localhost:9990 (No connection provider for URI scheme "http-remoting" is installed)].  My admin console : Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to expose a JBoss hosted datasource to a remote client with JBoss EAP 6.4.

A different process (JVM) on the same host is even a remote client for a JBoss application server.

As far as I know, it was possible before but not recommended.

**EDIT:**

You may provide a service API using EJBs to realize certain actions on your JBoss hosted datasource.

Comment: press F to pay respects